# Two levels of layout include - Android

Tags: android, layout, include

I have 3 layouts : 'a', 'b', 'c'.

'a' is included on 'b', and 'b' is included on 'c'. but when c rendered it shows me the content of 'b' only without 'a'.

is that because I can't have multilevel includes?

the layouts code:

a :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/AdInfoDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/AdNo"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="العدد"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/AdStatusGroup"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/AdStatus1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/excellent" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/AdStatus2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/good" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/AdStatus3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/bad" />


        </RadioGroup>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/BadAdInfoDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchLayout"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">


        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/BadAdStatusGroup"
            android:layout_width="294dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="4">

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/BadAdStatus1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/excellent" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/BadAdStatus2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/good" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/BadAdStatus3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/bad" />


        </RadioGroup>


    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

b :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/zainInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchLayout"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:background="#D8BFD8"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/zainInfoDetails1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:orientation="horizontal">




            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/zainStickCB"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/stickers"
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                android:textSize="20dp" />


            <include layout="@layout/ad_type" android:id="a"/>


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/zainInfoDetails2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/zainDangCB"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/danglers"
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                android:textSize="20dp" />


            <include layout="@layout/ad_type" android:id="a"/>



        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/zainInfoDetails3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/searchLayout"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/zainWashCB"
                android:layout_width="105dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_gravity="fill"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="@string/wash_lines"
                android:textDirection="rtl"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <include layout="@layout/ad_type" android:id="a" />

        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

c :-

```
<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mtnInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/searchLayout"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:background="#FFFFE0"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:visibility="visible">




               <include layout="@layout/b"


            </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your layout `b` change the filling to `wrap_content`

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

to

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

This goes for every kind of layout you wish to include. As soon as you set it to `match_parent` other layouts will have no space.

Comment: change it, nothing changed :/

Comment: @AhmedAbdElmoniem What exactly did you do?

Comment: @AhmedAbdElmoniem Wait, you are literally using `match_parent` on every single layout. Fix that with `wrap_content`. Otherwise the layouts have no space for each other, because there is the one with `match_parent` taking them all.